# raven query on object type throws exception

Tags: linq, ravendb

document Structure:

```
class UserAccountInfo
{
       public String Id { get; set; }
       public AccountType AccountType { get; set; }Servicetax
       public String MainAccountMobileNo { get; set; }
       public UserStatus Status { get; set; }
       public String EmailId { get; set; }
       public String DisplayName { get; set; }
       **public Object User { get; set; }**
}
```

object stores instance of any type that is mentioned in Account type. the type that is stored in the object can be found using Accountype for ex; if Accountype is customer then instance stored in the object will be AccountinfoCustomer and so on. So using that I've tried to query but getting the following exception from raven.

```
var Result = sess.Query<UserAccountInfo>().Where(x => x.AccountType == usertype && ((AccountInfoCustomer)x.User).Customerstatus == CustomerStatus.Pending);
```

{"Url: \"/indexes/dynamic/UserAccountInfos?query=AccountType%253ADistributor%2520AND%2520User).Customerstatus%253APending&start=0&pageSize=128&aggregation=None\"\r\n\r\nSystem.ArgumentException: The field ')_Customerstatus' is not indexed, cannot query on fields that are not indexed\r\n at Raven.Database.Indexing.Index.IndexQueryOperation.AssertQueryDoesNotContainFieldsThatAreNotIndexes()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.  Tested in current stable RavenDB 2.0.2230.

Tests here: https://gist.github.com/4692351

Are you on an older version?

Comment: Matt. I've changed the build to latest build 2.0.2230. still that doesn't work for me.And the exception i get is.[System.InvalidOperationException] = {"Url: \"/indexes/dynamic/UserAccountInfos?query=User).Customerstatus%253APending&start=0&pageSize=128&aggregation=None\"\r\n\r\nLucene.Net.QueryParsers.ParseException: Could not parse: 'User).Customerstatus:Pending' ---> Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.ParseExcept... Is there any specific libraries that you have added for this query to get executed.

Comment: Sorry Matt.. that was my mistake i didn't update the raven client library that's what caused the problem. Now its working thanks